# How to fix error refactoring decltype inside template

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, decltype

*edit* Possibly can't be done, see [Clean implementation of function template taking function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701018/clean-implementation-of-function-template-taking-function-pointer?rq=1) although answer 1 there has a C macro work-around https://stackoverflow.com/a/18706623/2332068

---

I'm passing a function into a template to become a pre-supplied argument to the constructor, but also need to use `decltype` on that function to pass the function type to `unique_ptr<...>` template instantiator(? is that the right word)

It works if I pre-use `decltype` as an extra template argument, but not if I invoke it inside the template on the function passed as a parameter.

I'm using g++ 4.9.2, and extending my explorations here [Calling inherited template constructor of unique_ptr subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418029/calling-inherited-template-constructor-of-unique-ptr-subclass) where I subclass `unique_ptr` to have a fixed destructor, I find that some destructor functions do not return `void`, so I want a more generic template that does not need to specify the destructor function type.

My current code is:

```
void free_int(int* p) {
  delete p;
}

template<typename T, void (*D)(T*)>
class unique_dptr : public std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(D)> {
    public: unique_dptr(T* t) : std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(D)>(t, D) { };
};

using int_ptr = unique_dptr<int, ::free_int>;
int_ptr i(new int(2));
```

but note the `void (*D)(T*)` calling signature to restrict the destructor to a void function that takes a pointer to `T`

Given normal use of `unique_ptr` in this form:

```
unique_ptr<foo, decltype(&::free_foo)>
```

I want to have something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename D>
class unique_gptr : public std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(&D)> {
    public: unique_gptr(T* t) : std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(&D)>(t, D) { };
};

using int_gptr = unique_gptr<int, ::free_int>;
int_gptr ig(new int(2));
```

but the compiler hates it:

```
error: template argument 2 is invalid
class unique_gptr : public std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(&D)> {
                                                          ^
```

No doubt ancient C-macro style token pasting is what I am wrongly aiming at.

I have tried removing the `&` from `decltype(&D)` but that leaves the error:

```
error: argument to decltype must be an expression
```

however this is OK:

```
template<typename T, typename D, D F>
class unique_gptr : public std::unique_ptr<T, D> {
    public: unique_gptr(T* t) : std::unique_ptr<T, D>(t, F) { };
};

using int_gptr = unique_gptr<int, decltype(&::free_int), ::free_int>;
int_gptr ig(new int(2));
```

but I wonder what I am doing wrong that I can't manage move the `decltype(&::free_int)` into the template.

---

## Other solutions

I realise that I can just write additional specialisations for other fixed free-function types, replacing `void(*)(void*)`

I realise that I can override the `std::default_delete` for my type.

But this is really an exercise in template composition

Comment: _"Note the `void (*D)(T*)` calling signature to restrict the destructor to a void function that takes a pointer to T."_ And why is this a problem? If you add a specialization that also accepts `void (*D)(void*)`, doesn't that cover all deleter functions you can pass in a template argument?

Comment: strangely no, some destructor functions return an `int`, e.g. openssl's `BIO_free`. But your point is good - there are other solutions, but I'm exploring templates and wonder why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for c++11 it is impossible to achieve what you want.

> ```
> template<typename T, typename D>
> class unique_gptr : public std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(&D)> {
>     public: unique_gptr(T* t) : std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(&D)>(t, D) { };
> };
>
> using int_gptr = unique_gptr<int, ::free_int>;
> int_gptr ig(new int(2));
> ```

Notice that `decltype` is applied on `D`, which is declared as a `typename`. So `D` is a type. But `decltype` can't be used on a **type**.

Firstly the code tries to get the address of a type (`&`). Secondly, the argument of `decltype` is expected to be an **expression**, but not a type or "the address of a type". To make it easier to understand, we can say that `decltype` expects its argument to be a “variable”, like the following example.

```
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    decltype(i) j;
    decltype(int) k; /* Compiler error. */
    decltype(&int) l; /* Compiler error. */
    return 0;
}
```

You also want the compiler to replace `D` with `::free_int`. And `::free_int` is passed in as a [non-type template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter) argument. However `D` is a type template parameter. A non-type template parameter starts with an actual type (e.g. `int`, `struct a*` or a type template name). While a type template parameter starts with `typename` or `class`. An easier example for non-type template parameter,

```
template<int INIT>
void func2(void)
{
    decltype(INIT) j = INIT;
}

int main()
{
    func2<10>();
    return 0;
}
```

When you pass in a function pointer like `::free_int`, you need **a non-type template parameter**, which must be preceded by a type. And you want the type of the function pointer to be "replaceable". So the type of the function pointer has to be **a type template parameter**. These make them two template parameters.

That's the reason you need three template parameters in `template<typename T, typename D, D F>`, which is the best result you have.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very clear explanation. I suppose I had based my hopes on the user of `Handler handler` in the boost asio templates which made it appear as though this could be done, but no doubt they resolve down to a limited set fixed and specified function types in some inner templates.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `decltype` with a type as the goal is to obtain the type of a variable. But in `decltype(&D)`, `D` is a type.

I would rather pass throught a template function:

```
template<typename T, typename D, D F>
class unique_gptr : public std::unique_ptr<T, D> {
    public: unique_gptr(T* t) : std::unique_ptr<T, D>(t, F) { };
};

template <typename T, typename D>
unique_gptr<T, D F> make_unique_gptr(T pointer, D deleter)
{
    return unique_gptr<T, D, deleter>(pointer);
}

auto ptr = make_unique(new int(2), ::free_int);
```

Comment: I guess your first statement applies to the block of code in the question prefixed with *My current code is* and not the block prefixed with *I want to have something like this:* -- good correction, thanks.

I like your solution `make_unique`, having advantage of avoiding the need to specify the destructor type, or the `using` statement often used to hide that.

It has the disadvantage of requiring the destructor to be specified each use, which is the thing I wanted to avoid, hence my use of the `using` statement to hide the destructor function: `using int_gptr = unique_gptr<int, ::free_int>;`

Comment: As `deleter` is not (and can't be) `constexpr`, that doesn't work. You have to pass `D f` in the constructor (and remove it from template parameter).

Answer (score 1):

You can use some macro magic:

```
template<class T, class D, D d>
struct UniqueDeleter : public std::unique_ptr<T, D> {
    UniqueDeleter(T* t) : std::unique_ptr<T, D>(t, d) { };
};

template<class R, class T>
T decl_unique_deleter_ptr(R (*d)(T*));

#define DECL_UNIQUE_DELETER1(f) UniqueDeleter<decltype(decl_unique_deleter_ptr(&f)), decltype(&f), &f>
#define DECL_UNIQUE_DELETER2(T, f) UniqueDeleter<T, decltype(&f), &f>
#define DECL_UNIQUE_DELETER_GET_MACRO(_1, _2, NAME, ...) NAME
#define DECL_UNIQUE_DELETER_EXPAND(x) x
#define decl_unique_deleter(...) DECL_UNIQUE_DELETER_EXPAND(DECL_UNIQUE_DELETER_GET_MACRO( \
    __VA_ARGS__, DECL_UNIQUE_DELETER2, DECL_UNIQUE_DELETER1, _)(__VA_ARGS__))
```

Now you can use it like such:

```
decl_unique_deleter(int, free_int) ig(new int(2));
```

Or with `using` and some more magic:

```
using int_gptr = decl_unique_deleter(free_int); // If accepted pointer type matches.
int_gptr ig(new int(2));
```

---

I might also recommend an alternative solution:

```
auto i = new int(2);
BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_ALL(&) { delete i; };
```

Comment: Thanks @orlp. `decl_unique_deleter` is a sweet piece of work, that produces a type that can be used directly or with `using`. But `BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_ALL` is also perhaps what I should be looking at.